# SASS partials: to be or not to be

Tags: sass, code-organization

Any soild reason I should prefer the **sass partials** over **normal sass files** (w/o leading underscore in the filename)?

I am not a full-time frontend developer and for now I use sass for simple organizing of my css - split styles into different files(modules/components), variables, functions, in-place calculations, mixins - I think that's all I do.

In general I create a single **main** sass files that combines all the files together like that:

```
// main.scss

@import 'vars'
@import 'funcs'
@import 'layout'
@import 'component/modal'
// etc.
```

And recently I noticed there is such thing as partials.
From the documentation I understand partials are independent files that are not exists on their own and are always a part of some other bigger modules.
By this logic it looks like **vars.scss**, **funcs.scss** are good candidates to be partials.

And what I can't understand is why **_vars.scss** is better than **vars.scss**.
The both variants will work well from the point of view of code splitting.

**Possible reason is Compilation** - [the docs page says](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4) partials will not be compiled into separate css file. I can't agree that's a feature since it's fully under my control and depends only on how I configure the building tools I use. And anyway such sass internal things like variables/functions/mixins will never be translated directly to css - they only exist in the source code.

So I would like to understand maybe it's just a **convention** for **visual separation** internal files from others? You know there is a similar old practice of separation private/public members/variables in programming. Or maybe I just miss something?

Please advise what I can do with partials what I cannot do with normal files, are there any advantages of first ones?

Comment: The underscore in _vars.scss is so your compiler knows it's meant to be imported only. So it doesn't compile the file on itself. Handy if you automatically compile an entire directory. Also it's a visual distinction between main files and import files

Comment: If you use the `@use` and `@forward` at-rules, you can create namespaces for those partials, something like `@include utils.mymixin()`. This may be usefull if you use other SASS libraries with helpers/utilities with the same name as yours.

Comment: @jrswgtr thanks for the reply. So again from your explanations it sounds more like "syntactic sugar". In case of compilation I don't see a problem to add a glob rule like "exclude: '_*.scss'" for my compiler/builder

Comment: @eMontielG I never used `@forward` and `@use` rules before but from the doc pages and quick tests it doesn't look these rules are limited to partials only - they work with normal sass files as well. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @PavelSadchenko in a way it is, but some compilers already use it as a convention so you don't need to add the "glob rule". They will ignore and not compile a file that starts with `_` That's the point